# How to handle time in Java

Tags: java, date, time, scheduling

I'm working on a functionality related to job scheduling in Java, where I'm required to schedule jobs based on days, weeks, or hours.

I'm running into 2 problems:

- What is a good representation/library to handle a duration of time (not date)?
- What is a good library to parse a text representation of time, i.e. 2d 3wk for 3 weeks and 2 days? similary to what [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) has for their.

I'm thinking this must've been done before, but I can't seem to find the correct word to google it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JODA time library http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ gives some nice Java time functionality. You may have to write some regular expressions to parse the type of text strings you're talking about though.

For scheduling the jobs, the Quartz scheduler http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/;jsessionid=LDKHONNCOPJC may be useful to you.

Comment: JODA time seems to be the standard, and it's looking good from the API too. Thanks object and Valentin Rocher, I'll tick Jeff for the most detailed answer.

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now on maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is THE reference for handling date in Java.

Comment: I remember using this for an application I made to count the hours I'd have to sleep, which would sit in the system tray and warn me when I was going under my allocated sleep quota :) It was pretty cool and handled everything.

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now on maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Quartz](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/;jsessionid=LDKHONNCOPJC), it s a powerful cron like system for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse a jira style time string into seconds using Joda time using something like this:

```
import org.joda.time.format.*;
```

import org.joda.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JiraStyleTimeParser
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String example = "1h 1m 30s";

MutablePeriod parsedPeriod = new MutablePeriod();

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
    .appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
    .appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
    .appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
    .printZeroAlways()
    .toFormatter();


PeriodParser parser = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
    .appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
    .appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
    .appendSeparator(" ")
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
    .printZeroAlways()
    .toParser();

int working = parser.parseInto(parsedPeriod, example,0, new Locale("en"));
System.out.println(formatter.print(parsedPeriod));

Duration theduration = parsedPeriod.toPeriod().toStandardDuration();
System.out.println("period in seconds: " + theduration.getStandardSeconds());

}
```

}

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now on maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time
>   classes. The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still
>   providing a simple API. The 'default' calendar is the ISO8601 standard
>   which is used by XML. The Gregorian, Julian, Buddhist, Coptic,
>   Ethiopic and Islamic systems are also included, and we welcome further
>   additions. Supporting classes include time zone, duration, format and
>   parsing.

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now on maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way to use Quartz is probably by using the interface to it that Spring Framework provides, here's a link to the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz).

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes classes found bundled with Java 8 and later and back-ported to earlier versions.

### `Duration`

To represent a span of time with a granularity of seconds-minutes-hours-days, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

### `Period`

To represent a span of time with a granularity of days-months-years, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html).

### ISO 8601

Also, study up on standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) formats for strings representing date-time values.

For spans of time, the standard uses the format `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing and generating strings.

```
String output = duration.toString();
```

> PT1H30M

```
Duration duration = Duration.parse( "PT1H30M" );
```

### ThreeTen-Extra

See the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project for more classes such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), a plural amount of `Days` & `Weeks` & `Months` & `Years`, quarters, and standard [ISO 8601 weeks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).